# How to use puppet resources as requirements only?

Tags: puppet

I have the following puppet configuration:

- An `Archive` resource (`A`) that executes only if the folder `/opt/dir` doesn't exist yet
- An `Exec` resource (`E0`) that mounts a SAMBA share where to retrieve the archive
- An `Exec` resource (`E1`) that unmounts the same SAMBA share

At the moment, `A` requires `E0` and when done, executes `E1`. However, even if the `A` isn't executed, `E0` and `E1` are still executed. This is probably due to the fact that `E0` and `E1` are part of another class (this is needed since they are required by others resources than `A`) and thus included with the `include` directive.

My question is: Is there a way to *define* `E0` and `E1` resources as *requirements* resources and not resources to execute *per se*?

Thank you all.

Comment: The short answer is no. That said, could you make `E0` and `E1` conditional with `onlyif` or `creates` so they only execute if their target state hasn't already been achieved?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I already thought of that and tried to work with these fields but there is no such condition.